# Why doesn't a limit exist if you have 0 in the denominator?

Tags: calculus

Say I want to find the limit of $f(x) = \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ at some 'a'. I've been told the limit doesn't exist if ever the denominator q(x) went to zero but not the numerator. Why is this?

Comment: This is because your fraction doesn't approach any number at all; it just increases without bound

Comment: Because $0/c$ is just $0$, but $c/0$ is not defined in most contexts. Does not have much to do with limits. Or do you ask why $c/0$ is bad?

Comment: @M.Winter It has _everything_ to do with limits. Taking limits is _not_ the same as inserting $x = a$ and evaluating. Even more so if you allow discontinuous functions.

Comment: @Arthur Well, ok. It has something to so with limits. But the problem arises before that when one asks why it is bad to divide by zero.

Comment: @M.Winter No, that's not where the problem arises. The definition of limits specifically avoids the exact point of interest $a$, and asks what happens on _every other point_ in the immediate vicinity of $a$t. And at these other points in the vicinity, $\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ is (at least in most problems given) an unproblematic fraction.

Comment: @Arthur I do not see how you can disagree so much?! $p(x)/q(x)$ is continuous (wherever it is defined), hence $\lim_{x\to a}p(x)/q(x)=p(a)/q(a)$ (wherever it is defined). So it is natural to assume this holds when $q(a)=0$, except it does not which can be explained by division by zero. Because OP does not really reveals his level of math education, I will start as low as possible and will not argue with the precise definition of limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps that I would take to prove it, under the assumption that $p$ and $q$ are continuous (without that assumption, or something very like it, there really isn't much you can do in general):

1. Assume the limit exists, and is some real number $L\in \Bbb R$
2. Use the following known facts in concert to derive a contradiction:

   - The definition of $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{p(x)}{q(x)} = L$
   - $q(a) = 0 \neq p(a)$
   - $p$ and $q$ are continuous

---

**Edit:** Thorough working out:

We ultimately want to disprove that $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{p(x)}{q(x)} = L$, so we just need to find a single $\epsilon>0$ that makes a contradiction. I pick $1$, because I like it (and because I actually know that they will all fail, so it doesn't matter which one I pick, so I go for one that is easy to work with). Since we assumed that the limit existed, that must mean that there is a $\delta>0$ that fulfills the definition $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{p(x)}{q(x)} = L$ for this specific value of $\epsilon$. In other words, for any $x\in (a-\delta, a+\delta)\setminus \{a\}$, we have
$$
\left|\frac{p(x)}{q(x)} - L\right|<1\\
\left|\frac{p(x) - Lq(x)}{q(x)}\right|<1\\
\frac{|p(x)-Lq(x)|}{|q(x)|}<1\\
|p(x) - Lq(x)| < |q(x)|
$$
Now let's use that $p$ and $q$ are continuous. $p$ being continuous means that there is a $\delta_p>0$ such that for any $x\in (a-\delta_p, a+\delta_p)$, we have $|p(x) - p(a)|<\frac{|p(a)|}2$ (here we use that $p(a)\neq 0$). This, in turn, means that $|p(x)|>\frac{|p(a)|}2$.

Similarily, we know that there is some $\delta_q>0$, such that for any $x\in (a-\delta_q, a+\delta_q)$ we have $|q(x)-q(a)| = |q(x)| <\frac{|p(a)|}{2(|L| + 1)}$ (here we also use that $p(a) \neq 0$, along with $q(a) = 0$). This, in turn, means that $(|L| + 1)|q(x)|<\frac{|p(a)|}{2}$.

If we now assume that $x\in (a-\delta_p, a+\delta_p)\cap (a-\delta_q, a+\delta_q)$, we can chain these two implications together to get
$$
|Lq(x)| + |q(x)| < \frac{|p(a)|}{2} < p(x)\\
|q(x)|<|p(x)| - |Lq(x)|\\
|q(x)|<|p(x) - Lq(x)|
$$
Now, let $\delta_f = \min(\delta, \delta_p, \delta_q)$, and pick an $x\in (a-\delta_f, a+\delta_f)\setminus\{a\}$, which is possible since $\delta_f>0$. For such an $x$, we have both $|q(x)|<|p(x) - Lq(x)|$ and $|p(x) - Lq(x)| < |q(x)|$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: how to deduce contradiction? my attempt:$|\frac{p(x)}{q(x)} - L| < \epsilon \implies q(x)(L-\epsilon ) < p(x) <q(x)(L+\epsilon)$ when ever $x \in (a-\delta , a+\delta)$ 

as $x \to a$ we get in above $p(a) \to 0$ (by squeeze theorem)

Comment: okay, let the limit be L. you have limit p(x) *limit 1/q(x) = L. This is because they're continous. limit 1/q(x) = L/limit(p(x)). But first limit doesn't exist therefore limit doesn't exist. Does this look alright?

Comment: @Vrisk I added a (hopefully rather exhaustive) proof using the definitions directly.

Comment: You assumed p and q are polynomials. -1

Comment: @windircurse There. I added a small clause, and changed three words in the entire answer. Don't know how such an insignificant mistake earned a -1, but at least you told me (which is better than many downvotes I get).

Comment: If you just relabel $p(a)$ with a variable $b$ everywhere, and $q(a)$ with $0$, I don't think your proof changes.  So you're not really using the extra assumption that $p$ and $q$ are continuous at $a$; you're just assuming the limits exist.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang You're right. That they both have a limit at $a$ is a weaker condition that works. I also realised that I haven't really looked into the consequences of $q$ having other zeroes arbitrarily close to $a$. Quite possibly the only thing I need to do is to add the condition "where it exists" to $\left|\frac{p(x)}{q(x)} - L\right|<1$. I'll look into it when next I have the time.

Answer (score 1):

Because then the value $|f(x)|$ becomes bigger than any $M\in\mathbb R$, therefore no value can be the limit.

Answer (score 1):

You can appeal to the definition of limit, or you can use the product law and prove this by contradiction:

*Suppose that $\lim_{x\to a} p(x) = b \neq 0$, and $\lim_{x\to a} q(x) = 0$.  Then $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ does not exist.*

**Proof** Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{p(x)}{q(x)} = L$.  Then
$$
    \lim_{x\to a} p(x) = \lim_{x\to a} \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}\cdot q(x)
    = \lim_{x\to a} \frac{p(x)}{q(x)} \cdot \lim_{x\to a} q(x)
    = L \cdot 0 = 0
$$
But this contradicts the assumption that $\lim_{x\to a} p(x)\neq 0$.

Comment: isn't there division by 0 in your first step - more precisely 0/0   != 1

Comment: nvm, i got it. thanks, really neat and simple +1

Answer (score 0):

Try it yourself (and use a calculator if you want). Choose a small number $x$, e.g. $x=0.001$, and compute both

$$\frac x1,\qquad\qquad \frac 1x.$$

Now choose a smaller number for $x$, e.g. $x=0.00001$, and compute again. Do this again and again with smaller numbers. Can you see how $x/1$ becomes smaller and smaller, almost zero? Can you see how this is *not* the case for $1/x$? It gets bigger and bigger instead and there is no number for which we can say that the sequence approches it (and no, $\infty$ is no number).

It does not really matter what is on the other side of the quotient. When only the numerator vanishes, everything tends to zero. When only the denominator vanishes, everything tends to explode.